# How do I quickly sort hispanic from anglo names contained in an Excel sheet?

Tags: sorting

Looking for a fast way to segregate hispanic names from anglo names from a list of over 10,000 entries.  List that includes several fields all contained within columns.

Comment: How can you be sure if a name is Hispanic or Anglo? What about those with Hispanic names who are culturally Anglo or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're going to need tables of Anglo names and Hispanic names.

However, you're going to have real problems. Googling "1000 most common english first names" led me [here](http://www.behindthename.com/top/lists/sp/2012) (1st link), which in turn led me [here](http://www.behindthename.com/top/lists/sp/2012). I noticed that many of the "Spanish" names are exact equivalents to English/American (i.e. Anglo(-Saxon)) ones (rough guess, 20%).

You'd probably be better as Googling "1000 most common spanish sunnames" - gave me [this](http://names.mongabay.com/data/hispanic.html) - much less ambiguity as far as I can see. If I were you, I would do the best I can with surnames - any final ambiguities, just put 50/50 into one or the other on a random basis - or exclude them. It really depends on what you're ultimate goal in this study is. As an aside, interestingly, "Murphy", which is neither, is on the list - what do you do for those which fall between your two stools?

Finally, Have you posted under two different identities (i.e. Alex Parra and AlexPM)? If so, could you please refrain from this, as it complicates answers and will confuse posters.

Comment: Ah, sorry, posting from mobile and didn't see your answer while typing mine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've resolved the two user names issue.

Thanks for your research. It seems I can't get away without putting some time into it.

These are parishioner's data files createD on a software called ParishSoft. i don't have access to this software. I only receive the files in excel format. My goal is to split each file into two: Spanish speaking and English speaking.

The way I've been doing it is adding a column next to the name column and scrolling  down the spreadsheet identifying with say an "s" those Who most likely are Hispanic when I know the data is predominantly anglo. Then autofilter, cut and paste to create a second file.

This was not a problem when files contained 3,000 entries or less. But 10,000 is going to take some time.

Your help is very much appreciated.